# How to say "Hopefully we can treat each other with more X"

Tags: grammar, mandarin, cantonese

Is there a general template for translating, "hopefully we can treat each with more X" where X is some noun.

Examples:

- Hopefully we can treat each other with more consideration.
- Hopefully we can treat each other with more generosity.
- Hopefully we can treat each other with more thoughtfulness.

Is this different for Cantonese and Mandarin?

These translations don't quite feel right (for consideration):

- 希望我們可更互相體貼
- 希望大家對大家有更多體貼

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **A**:
>
> English grammar: [1. hopefully] [2. we can] [3. treat each other] [4. with more (n)]
>
> Chinese grammar: [1. hopefully] [2. we can] [3. with more (n)] [4. treat each other]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們能] [3. 以更多(n)] [4. 互相對待]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們能] [3. 以更多寬容] [4. 互相對待]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們能] [3. 以更多體諒] [4. 互相對待]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們能] [3. 以更多體貼] [4. 互相對待]

> **B**:
>
> English grammar: [1. hopefully] [2. we can] [3. treat each other] [4. more (adv)]
>
> Chinese grammar: [1. hopefully] [2. we can] [3. more (adv)] [4. treat each other]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們能] [3. 更(adv)] [4. 互相對待]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們能] [3. 更寬容地] [4. 互相對待]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們能] [3. 更體諒地] [4. 互相對待]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們能] [3. 更體貼地] [4. 互相對待]

> **C**:
>
> English grammar: [1. hopefully] [2. we can] [3. be more (adj)] [4. with each other]
>
> Chinese grammar: [1. hopefully] [2. we ] [3. with each other] [4. can be more (adj)]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們] [3. 互相之間] [4. 能更 (adj)]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們] [3. 互相之間] [4. 能更寬容]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們] [3. 互相之間] [4. 能更友好]

[1. 希望] [2. 我們] [3. 互相之間] [4. 能更體貼]

*You can replace 希望 with 但願; replace 能 with 能夠 or 可以; replace 更 with 更加*

```
(A)is a less common way to speak in Chinese compare to (B) or (C)
```

~

> Cantonese:
>
> [1. 希望] [2. 我地能夠] [3. 以更多(n)] [4. 互相對待]
>
> [1. 希望] [2. 我地能夠] [3. 更(adv)] [4. 互相對待]
>
> [1. 希望] [2. 我地] [3. 互相之間] [4. 能夠更(adj)]

[1. 希望] [2. 我地能夠] [3. 以更多寬容] [4. 互相對待]

[1. 希望] [2. 我地能夠] [3. 更寬容噉] [4. 互相對待]

[1. 希望] [2. 我地] [3. 互相之間] [4. 能夠更寬容]

*You can replace 希望 with 但願; replace 能夠 with 可以; replace 更 with 更加*

Comment: thank you once again! very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It think there may be a problem with your translation because

Hopefully we can treat each other with more X

is not very "complete" in Chinese
I'll change the sentence to

Hopefully we can treat each other with more X in the future

first before the translation, so in Chinese it is

希望 *以後* 我們可以/會對彼此有更多X
for example, 希望以後我們會對彼此有更多體諒
or 希望我們可以對彼此有更多體諒